# How can I be sure my UK company pay into my pension fund?

Tags: united-kingdom, company-policy, company

As everybody else in the UK, I have to pay some money for my pension and the company has to contribute to it for a minimum of 3%.

For what I read, the company has maximum 30 days to send the money taken from my salary plus its part to the pension company. The pension company will add the money to my pension pot in maximum 7 days.

After few months, I couldn't see any change on pension pot. So, I asked to the pension company why and they said that they haven't received the money from my company yet.

My company said that they sent the money regularly.

Now, I don't know who speaks the truth. I think the salary sacrifice for the pension and the contribution from the company is a right and also this is my money.

What can I do to understand who holds my money and have regular payments?

Comment: Is this a defined benefits or defined contributions pension scheme? Also, what did the company say when you asked if they had transferred the money? And how long do they think they have to transfer it?

Comment: Defined contributions pension scheme

Comment: I have known situations in the past where employees pensions were never paid and the company went under. Generally employees are last in the line when it comes to asset liquidation of a company, so it's best you get on top of this.

Comment: What do your payslips say?

Comment: In the UK the employee should be able to claim unpaid pension contributions (and other money they're _already_ owed) from the "National Insurance Fund" if their employer becomes insolvent, so it probably isn't a long-term disaster (but maybe should be treated as a warning sign). What they usual lose is money that they were owed in future (e.g. notice pay)

Comment: Do you have any approachable colleagues who you can ask (without mentioning amounts obviously) whether they are having the same issue - I think the approach will depend on whether it's just you (probable admin error) or more systemic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> For what I read, the company has maximum 30 days to send the money taken from my salary plus its part to the pension company. The pension company will add the money to my pension pot in maximum 7 days.

If the money hasn't been paid to your pension provider in 90 days you can report it to the Pensions Regulator [here](https://www.thepensionsregulator.gov.uk/en/contact-us/scheme-members-who-to-contact/report-concerns-about-your-workplace-pension/report-missing-payments-to-your-workplace-pension). You mention that it's been "a few months" so it's possible that these 90 days have already been met, While this is a nuclear option, and you should probably raise the matter (in writing!)  with your employer *first* as there may be a simple administrative error behind it after all HR/Payroll are human and human errors *do* happen. Of course if they have been withholding the money deliberately this is a serious issue, one that can land the company in some nasty trouble legally.